# how to find the location of ssh folder used by openshift? Is there any way to change it?

Tags: ssh, openshift

I have two users folder in my machine, both contains .ssh folder. I am confused which is the folder used by my openshift. Is there any way that I can find the location of .ssh folder that openshift is using and is it possible to change the location of that folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the rhc setup command, or have uploaded your public key manually using the OpenShift Online console, you can visit the settings page (https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/settings) and look at the "Contents" column of the "Public Keys" table.  It will show the first few characters, and the last few characters, of the public key that was used.  You can then compare that to the public key(s) in your ssh folder(s) under your different user accounts on your computer and determine which one is being used.